# How can I break block elements apart in CSS grid?

Tags: html, css, jekyll, css-grid

### The question

I'm wondering how to 'break out' elements within block elements (such as a `<section>` tag) out of their inherent *rectangular shape*. Using CSS grid.

### An example

See [this example](http://dannywhite.is/fluid-css-grid/full.html) of a desired end result. It would ideally keep the integrity of an `<article>` tag whilst also allowing children such as the `<header>`, `<figcaption>`, and `<img>` to move around the parent grid—sitting alongside or before other parent-level elements such as the `<nav>`. The markup of this example is purposely poor for visualisation purposes.

### The reason I need to do it this way

I'm using [Jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com) to generate my blog posts and would like elements *within* a Markdown-to-HTML-generated post (such as images, image captions) to visually break apart-from and mix-within other page elements. This means I can't pre-format posts with `<div>` or `<section>` tags.

### The (desired) code

```
<body>
    <nav>
      <h1>Nav header</h1>
      <ul>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
        <li>Item</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <article>
      <header>
        <h1>Article header</h1>
        <p>Posted today</p>
      </header>

        <h2>Article body</h2>
        <p>Behold was them gathered bring brought sea called. Stars given and, which life.</p>

        <p>Us divided may divide without bring given unto likeness together form you&#39;ll open let, which. Under. One kind have is.</p>

        <figure>
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1492854536278-1f94bbec5732?auto=format&fit=crop&w=1950&q=80" alt="Scotland">
          <figcaption>This is the caption for the image on the right.</figcaption>
        </figure>

        <p>Very face, morning was is god wherein multiply was in. Void own.</p>

        <p>Green. Called fish beast i creepeth. Is. Behold place which upon saw. Don&#39;t had. Earth. Darkness signs sea had had. Sea itself from. It given.</p>

    </article>
  </body>
```

Comment: Please post your code in the question so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Good call. Just added. Thanks @Michael_B